# MacOS/Safari double extensions when using ImageResizer

Tags: imageresizer, imageresizer-diskcache

We are converting large PNG images to JPEG using ImageResizer (https://imageresizing.net/). It's works great with ?format=jpg and they are delivered with the correct content type and all.

When downloading these images they are named image.jpg in all browsers except Safari. Here it asks the user if they want to go with .jpg or with .png. It also saves the images as image.png.jpg which is confusing for some users.

I read something about Content-Disposition header, but I think that's for direct download, not for right click and choosing Save as. I also don't know if it would be possible to add it without creating some kind of middle layer and probably lose performance.

Ideas? Thanks <3

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a solution to this, as it is in the browser's control.